# How to set Windows date by visual basic

Tags: vba, basic

I am looking to **set Windows date** by visual basic.
All I need is a small form with one button, every time I click the button, Windows date increased one day.

I know to do such a task I have to go offline first, because Windows will synchronize the clock to correct date with the Internet.

Also, to retrieve current Datetime, I can do like this:

```
Dim x as date
x = DateTime.now
```

But I am not sure how to add one day and update the system with the new date.

Comment: That method on the mentioned answer does not work.

Answer (score 0):

you may use dateadd function, please sample below.

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim newDate As Date

newDate = DateAdd("d", 1, Now())

MsgBox Format(newDate, "yyyy/mm/dd")

End Sub

Comment: This example is to retrieve system date and add one day then show it as Msgbox. I want to update the operating system date ( add one day each time I click the button). Thank you.

Comment: alright, if you need to change the system date you may use the code below. make sure you have the right access to modify the systemdate.

Date = DateAdd("d", Now(), 1)